# Variables. scope inside of a cfmodule

Tags: scope, coldfusion, cfc, coldfusion-2016

I have a page with a name of

**summary.cfm**

inside of it:

```
 <cfinclude template="view/totals.cfm>
```

**view/totals.cfm**

inside of it:

```
variables.grandTotalHTML = invoke("viewtotals, "doSummary", {...});
```

**view/viewtotals.cfc**

inside of it

```
<cfmodule template="summarytemplate.cfm" ...>
<!--- database is not passed in here --->
```

**view/summarytemplate.cfm**

Inside of it we have

```
param attributes.database = session.database;
...
databaseoverride = attributes.database;
...

<cfquery name="qData">
   SELECT *
   FROM [#variables.databaseoverride#]
   ...
</cfquery>
```

**Now question**

I don't know where the databaseoverride is coming from.

1. Does global page request scope?
2. Does it come from variables in `viewtotals.cfc` ?
3. Does the unscoped version override it?

Comment: Can you clarify that issue. You say you don't know where the databaseoverride is coming from but you are showing it set in summarytemlate.cfm. Note: I assumed you made a typo when I saw "databaseboverride" but maybe that was not the case....?

Comment: that was a typo, let me fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Too long for comments)

Just to elaborate on [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57912897/8895292):

**summary.cfm**

- Only shares a `VARIABLES` scope with the included template, "view/totals.cfm"

**view/totals.cfm**

- Only shares a `VARIABLES` scope with the parent template, "summary.cfm"

**view/viewTotals.cfc**

- Its `VARIABLES` scope is **not** shared with any of the calling templates (summary.cfm and view/totals.cfm)
- Its `VARIABLES` are **accessible** to the cfmodule - through the `CALLER` scope (as are the function's `local` and `arguments` scopes)

**view/summaryTemplate.cfm**

- Does **not** share its `VARIABLES` scope with anyone.
- **Can** view/modify any scopes in the parent component (viewTotals.cfc) through the `CALLER` scope.

( The `REQUEST` scope is accessible to all of the scripts above.)

Answer (score 2):

The variables scope at the module level is local to the module. An unscoped variable in a module is in variables scope.

This line

```
databaseoverride = attributes.database;
```

is equivalent to

```
variables.databaseoverride = attributes.database;
```

so is setting the value used here

```
<cfquery name="qData">
   SELECT *
   FROM [#variables.databaseoverride#]
   ...
</cfquery>
```

Comment: ColdFusion has (at least) two different `variable.` scopes. One that inside of a cfc and one that is outside of a cfc. I am looking at the cfmodule which is called by a cfc and wondering where its variables is coming from

Comment: the variables scope of the cfc is not accessible by the cfmodule. It has a way to reference a caller scope which is how you would normally be able to reference variables outside of it though I have not tried it in the context of a cfc